# Write VTK in parallel C++ with MPI

Tags: c++, vtk, openmpi, paraview

I am new to `C++` and I've just started to write a `CFD` (Computational Fluid Dynamics) code in parallel hybrid mode (`MPI + CUDA`). 
I would like to know if you have any references  on how to write parallel `VTK` files using `MPI`?

Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Andrei, I am not an expert on this subject. However, have a look at the parallel xml writers in vtk (e.g. vtkxmlpdatasetwriter, etc.).

Comment: Thanks. I will have a look!

Answer (score 3):

I think [this](https://gerstrong.github.io/blog/2016/08/20/hacking-vtk-for-parallelisation) is maybe the simplest way you can do it:

1. Each process write its own .vts file (for unstructured grid it is .vtu).
2. Master process writes a .pvts file which contains information of the whole domain.
3. Open the .pvts file in ParaView or other softwares.

For details see the [link](https://gerstrong.github.io/blog/2016/08/20/hacking-vtk-for-parallelisation).